# Does Wiping Data/Internal SD in TWRP Remove files Permanently?

Tags: data-recovery, delete, remote-wipe

I am selling my Moto X Play and want to make sure all my personal files were permanently removed from the device.

I did a Factory Reset from within the OS twice and noticed that my photos would still appear after the reset was completed.

So then I booted into TWRP recovery mode and went to wipe and wiped the internal SD and Data on the device, booted back into the system and the pictures were all gone. I then flashed a completely different rom and pictures are still gone now.

I just want to confirm that at this point that my files are completely erased and could never be recovered.

Comment: [Can user data be recovered after formatting and flashing stock ROM?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214497/218526)

Answer (score 0):

Of course. If you see the process of working twrp, you'll see that it erase sdcard without wiping data/media that is sdcard0, in some cases. It contains all of your saved files like music etc